# Perform a constrained integration over $[-1,1]^6--yielding a "separability probability"

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, boolean-computation, constraint

To begin with, I have a set of three positivity constraints (ensuring the positivity of a certain (twelve-parameter) $6 \times 6$ "density matrix", denoted in the standard manner as $\rho$, namely,

```
C1 = 1 - t^2 - v^2 + 2 t v w - w^2 >0,

C2 = 1 - w^2 + (-1 + w^2) x^2 - y^2 + v^2 (-1 + y^2) + 2 w y z - z^2 + 
 2 v x (-w y + z) + t^2 (-1 + z^2) + 2 t (x (y - w z) + v (w - y z))>0
```

and (restricting the six variables to $[-1,1]^6$),

```
C3 = -1 < t < 1 && -1 < v < 1 && -1 < w < 1 && -1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1 && -1 < z < 1
```

I successfully perform the command

```
S = GenericCylindricalDecomposition[C1 && C2 && C3,{t, v, w, x, y, z}]
```

and, then,

```
Integrate[
    (27/(32 Pi^2) Boole[ S[[1]] ],
    {t, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, {w, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
]
```

yielding $1$.

Now, I have an additional two positivity constraints (note the new [seventh] variable $u \in [0,1]$),

```
C4 = -u^2 (-1 + t^2 + v^2) + 2 t u v x - x^2>0
```

and

```
C5 = -u^4 w^2 - x^2 + 2 u^3 w (t y + v z) + 2 u x (t v + y z) + 
 u^2 (1 - v^2 + w^2 x^2 - 2 v w x y + (-1 + v^2) y^2 - 
    2 t (w x + v y) z - z^2 + t^2 (-1 + z^2)) > 0
```

All the constraints (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5) together ensure both the positivity of the $\rho$ and its "partial transpose" (obtained by transposing in place its four $3 \times 3$ blocks). If all the constraints are satisfied, $\rho$ is "separable" (not entangled).

Ideally, I could now perform the commands

```
T = GenericCylindricalDecomposition[C1 && C2 && C3 && C4 && C5, {u, t, v, w, x, y, z}]
```

followed by,

```
Integrate[
  (27/(32 Pi^2)) Boole[ T[[1]] ], 
  {t, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, {w, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
]
```

This would give me a (conjecturally, simple) "separability function" of $u$, which when multiplied by

```
(15360 u^4 (-1 - 28 u^2 + 28 u^6 + u^8 - 24 (u^2 + 3 u^4 + u^6) Log[u]))/((-2048 + 225 π^2) (-1 + u^2)
```

and integrated over $u \in [0,1]$, would further yield an (again, conjecturally simple) "separability probability" associated with the (twelve-parameter) set of $\rho$'s matrices under consideration.

However, my attempt to perform the last indicated `GenericCylindricalDecomposition` command does not seem to terminate.

---

The "second-best" along these lines I seem able to do is to perform the command (the C2 constraint--ensuring the positivity of the determinant of $\rho$ is now omitted),

```
R = GenericCylindricalDecomposition[C1  && C3 && C4 && C5,{u, t, v, w, x, y, z}]
```

but also with the omission of $-1 < z < 1$ from the `C3` constraint.

So, can I somehow "piece together" `S` and `R` to solve my problem?

The solution to

```
Integrate[(27/(32 Pi^2))Boole[R[[1]],{t,-1,1},{v,-1,1},{w,-1,1},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]
```

is the function 3 u/5--which leads to a result

```
384/(5 (-2048+225 \[Pi]^2)) = 0.444802.
```

Also, earlier I tried the variation on the problem

```
P = GenericCylindricalDecomposition[C1  && C2 && C3 && C4,{u, t, v, w, x, y, z}]
```

which should provide me with an upper bound on the desired separability probability.

---

I obtained (but these results need to be rechecked)

```
(9 Pi^2 u (27-7 u^2))/2048
```

for the associated separability function, and

```
(27 Pi^2 (-689 + 70 Pi^2))/(-8192 + 900 Pi^2) \approx 0.722415
```

for the upper bound.

Of course, also, one should feel free to permute the order of the variables 
t,v,w,x,y,z. (This order seemed optimal for the original integration yielding 1, but might not be so for the full problem.)

Comment: Please re-check your equations after my formatting: I would ask you to completely avoid interspersing $\TeX$ with code as that defeats the purpose of providing copy/pastable code. Also, are you *quite sure* that you cannot conceive of a simpler system on which to ask your question? Otherwise, this appears to be extremely specific to your problem only.

Comment: Thanks, MarcoB--your reformatting seems fine. Well, unfortunately perhaps, this is a quite specific--and seemingly difficult problem--hard to see how I could suitably "downsize" it. I'll keep at it, however, for at least a little while. The  upper bound problem, to which I refer, seems somewhat more addressable.